# List Apache File Directory Tree To Download

Tags: apache-http-server, file-permissions, file-management, webserver

I found a website online running an `Apache` Webserver. It has a directory which looks something like the below.

```
main website
├───version 1.0
│       a.txt
│       b.txt
│       c.txt
│       d.txt
│
├───version 2.0
│       e.pdf
│       f.pdf
│
└───version 3.0
        g.pdf
        h.pdf
        i.pdf
```

The issue is that I do not have access to the `main website`.

[image]

But I have access to the files inside the directory tree. For example, I have access to `a.txt` and `i.pdf`. I do not know if there are other files like `b.txt` and `c.txt`

My question is, can I list out all the files that website tree contains. The output will be something like,

```
a.txt
b.txt
c.txt
d.txt
e.pdf
f.pdf
g.pdf
h.pdf
i.pdf
```

I want to download all the `*.pdf` files inside the directory. Let me know how I can achieve this. I can run anything on Windows or Linux.

Comment: You can only do that by reconfiguring the web server itself to allow listing directory content. Blocking directory listings is a security feature that’s enabled by default on Apache. If you don’t have access to the configuration of the web server, there’s no way.

Comment: @StarCat Does it mean if I do not have access to the `main website`, allow listing directory content is blocked?

Comment: Whether you have access to the main (`“/“`) website or not, is not relevant. You can only get directory content (of the main site or any underlying parts of the site“) if the webserver is configured for generating directory listings for that particular part of the site. It seems your site is not, and there’s nothing you can do *from the client side* to change that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How do I generate the directory listings in the case where the website's webserver is configured for generating directory listings?

Comment: You should be able to just browse to the (sub)site (not to a particular file), like: `https://website.com/` or `https://website.com/subsite/`. Apache will then automatically generate a (HTML) directory listing if configured to do so (and there's no index file like `index.html` to serve). See [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/HTTPD/DirectoryListings) for how this is configured on the web server. Remember most sites do not allow this.